# Outlook 365 - Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name

Tags: outlook

can anybody please advise me?

I want to set a question when I send mail in Outlook. I use this code:

```
 Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 


Public Sub Initialize_handler() 

 Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application 

End Sub 



Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 

 Dim prompt As String 

 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " &; Item.Subject &; "?" 

 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 

 Cancel = True 

 End If 

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I still get this error message:

*Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name*

I have the entire code in the "ThisOutlookSession" section. What am I doing wrong? Please for help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right use:

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

:-)

Answer (score 0):

`Cancel` parameter must be `ByRef`.

Comment: I tried. But it still does not work. It still tells me the same thing. Do I need to turn something into Outlook somewhere?

Comment: Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim prompt As String
    prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub